# Halide non-contiguous memory layout

Tags: python, numpy, halide

Is it possible to use non-c/fortran ordering in Halide? (where given dimensions x, y, c, x varies the fastest, then c varies the 2nd fastest (strides in numpy at least would be: `.strides = (W*C, 1, W)` Our memory layout is a stack of images where the channels of each image are stacked by scanline.

(Sorry if the layout still isn't clear enough, I can try to clarify). Using the python bindings, I always get `ValueError: ndarray is not contiguous when trying to pass in my numpy array with .strides set.`

I've tried changing the numpy array to use contiguous strides (without changing the memory layout) just to get it into Halide, then setting .set_stride in halide, but no luck. I'm just wanting to make sure I'm not trying to do something that can't/shouldn't be done.

I think this is similar to the line-by-line layout mentioned at https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_16_rgb_generate.html, except more dimensions in C since the images are "stacked" along channel (to produce a W, H, C*image_count tensor)

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a numpy question than a Halide one. The following Halide code illustrates use of an array in the shape you are looking for (I think):

```
import halide as hl
import numpy as np;

x, y, c = hl.Var('x'), hl.Var('y'), hl.Var('c')
f = hl.Func('f')
f[x, y, c] = (x * 3) + (y * 12) + c
# This would be necessary for internally allocated buffers
# f.reorder_storage(x, c, y)

# These control output layout
f.output_buffer().dim(1).set_stride(12)
f.output_buffer().dim(2).set_stride(3)
# Probably wanted for efficiency
f.reorder(x, c, y)
result = f.realize(4, 5, 3)

print(result, result[0, 1, 1])
np_result = np.array(result)
print(np_result, np_result[0, 1, 1])
print(np_result.shape, " ", np_result.strides, " ", np_result.flags)
```

I'm not well versed in numpy and not sure how you would allocate an array in that layout from scratch but the answer might have to be something like `lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`.